# How to merge two edges?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to merge these two edges, and have followed all the advice, but it's not working. Any attempt to merge them only results in some kind of muddled merge!

[image]

Comment: Check your normals are all facing the same way? Alt-N for the flip menu..

Comment: Are both edges from one object?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>G</kbd> moving vertices with Snap set to 'Vertex' and 'Active' with *Automerge* switched on will give you per-vertex control, and is a common way of  stitching up meshes ... <kbd>M</kbd> Merge > at Center for vertex-pairs.. so many ways.

One for edges is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*, with 'Merge' checked:

[image]

'Merge' will stay checked after use, and the operator can be used on multiple edges in parallel loops.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

The most successful way I found was to combine/merge the two objects, with `CTRL+K` , and then select all the vertices I wanted to merge, pressing `M` > By Distance, and in this case, because it's a too-scale far, selecting the distance as 40mm (4cm). Does all the hard work!